# Advisor uses student's work unethically

Tags: phd, research-process, advisor, computer-science

Alice's ex-advisor accused Alice of plagiarism. It wasn't plagiarism in any way and Alice tried to reason with her ex-advisor. It seemed at the time that they reached an understanding.

Alice's ex-advisor continued funding her over the next semester and made her finish the development of a technology. As soon as Alice finished developing it and handed over the code, her ex-advisor officially reported her for academic misconduct. Alice changed advisors right away, but now her ex-advisor is not letting her use the technology as part of her dissertation. So essentially, the ex-advisor made Alice finish the development of the tech without informing her that he is going to report her eventually. This seems unethical. Isn't this a violation of research integrity? If not, what kind of violation is this?

In the process, ex-advisor also violated university policy of reporting a misconduct with 14 calendar days. Under the above circumstances, what should Alice do? With the policy violation Alice can only fight the misconduct allegation, but still not get her work back. So how can Alice argue to get access to the tech that she developed?

Comment: You may want to name the country, so that readers familiar with a country's system may provide more targeted/useful feedback.    I see two separate issues: (i) plagiarism, and (ii) theft of technology.  The first issue involves Alice, and the second, involves the ex-advisor.  They should be handled separately by a university.  Alice should check her university's policy regarding intellectual property rights.

Comment: Plagiarism of what, and how? Is the plagiarism accusation related to the "technology" that Alice developed? The title says the advisor is *using* work unethically - what work are they using?

Comment: Your previous posts already cover most of this ground, and you received some good advice there. If there is something new, you can [edit] your post(s) to make it clear what the differences between these question are. A good starting place is to put the actual question (including a question mark!) in the title -- this will help you crystallize the question a bit beyond "what should I do?"